# Firebase onChildAdded is being triggered multiple times

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `ListView` that each row contains several `EditText` and a save `Button`.

In the ShowOrder activty i'm getting the data from Firebase

```
public void getItemsOrderDetails(final String key){

    orderDetailsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            arrayLength = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

            String itemN="", discription="", qty="", pcsCtn="", ctnWt="", compileStatus="", palletN="", ttlCtn="";
            if(!key.equals("costumerName") && !key.equals("dateOfDelivery") && !key.equals("dateOfOrder") && !key.equals("orderN") && !key.equals("remarks") && !key.equals("status")){
                if(dataSnapshot.child(key).hasChild("itemNumber")){
                     itemN= dataSnapshot.child(key).child("itemNumber").getValue().toString();
                }
               ...
               ... {downloading all data}
               ...

                itemsClass= new ItemsClass(orderNumber, itemN, discription, pcsCtn, ttlCtn, ctnWt, qty, compileStatus, palletN );
                itemsClassArrayList.add(itemsClass);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
```

I'm showing all the data at the `adapter` , and problem is when I want to update the data `onChildAdded` is beeing triggered multiple times.

This is the update part in the Adapter:

```
private void updateData(ViewHolder vh, String orderN){

    showOrder.itemsClassArrayList.clear();
        updateStatus="idle";         
    ordersRef.child(orderNumber).child(itemN).child("palletNo").setValue(pallete);
    ordersRef.child(orderNumber).child(itemN).child("pcsPizza").setValue(untCtn);
    ordersRef.child(orderNumber).child(itemN).child("compileStatus").setValue(collected);
    ordersRef.child(orderNumber).child(itemN).child("drink").setValue(ctnWt);
    ordersRef.child(orderNumber).child(itemN).child("ttlWt").setValue(pltWt);
    ordersRef.child(orderNumber).child(itemN).child("ttl").setValue(ttlCtn);
    updateStatus= "update";
    //showOrder.adapter.clear();

}
```

What I discovered is that if i'm updating only one `child` (Deleting all the others) the `onChildAdded` will be update only once.
So i don't understand how can i update all with out multiple Updating, if anyone as an idea.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a complete solution to your issue, but a few things struck me right away:

You can (and should) load and store complete Objects in your database, so instead of reading and writing each child (e.g. of your ItemsClass object) separately, you should store your item like so:

```
ordersRef.child(orderNumber).child(itemN).setValue(myItem)
```

where myItem is an instance of ItemsClass that has been populated with data before.

In a similar way, loading data should be done like so (depending on where orderDetailsRef points to! see below):

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
    ItemsClass items = dataSnapshot.getValue(ItemsClass.class); 
}
```

Also, you mention onChildAdded getting called multiple times, yet in your example you are using a ValueEventListener's onDataChange method.

Could you give a complete code sample? The one you posted is lacking relevant parts of your solution. And let me know how your code behaves when you load and save the way I suggested.